# How to add ssh keys via Ansible when AuthorizedKeysFile is set?

Tags: ssh, ansible

How can I get Ansible to populate the correct file when my */etc/ssh/sshd_config* has *AuthorizedKeysFile* set to */etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u*? Ansible seems to ignore the setting and places keys in *$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys*

**playbook**:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
  vars_files:
    - ../group_vars/ssh_root_authorized_keys.yml
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Set up multiple authorized keys
      authorized_key:
        user: root
        state: present
        key: '{{ item.key }}'
      with_items: "{{ root_auth_keys }}"
```

**ssh_root_authorized_keys.yml**

```
root_auth_keys:
  - name: backup@host
    key : "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/pubkeys/root@backup.pub') }}"

  - name: nagios@host
    key : "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/pubkeys/root@nagios.pub') }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html):

> path: Alternate path to the authorized_keys file

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Set up multiple authorized keys
      authorized_key:
        user: root
        state: present
        key: '{{ item.key }}'
        path: '/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/root'
      with_items: "{{ root_auth_keys }}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping Ansible was "path aware" but guess not. I suppose a `stat:` may help here as I have some hosts which do not have `AuthorizedKeysFile` set. Any easy way to determine if this sshd config item is different than default?  I'm thinking `shell:` or `cmd:` with `grep` but maybe not.

Comment: This doc is outdated

Comment: Thanks for notifying @MohammedNoureldin, I updated the URL. Feel free to suggest edits yourself when you encounter outdated URLs to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of steps to prepare this functionality. First, get the value of the parameter. There might be more options, e.g. by default

```sh
shell> sudo sshd -T | grep authorizedkeysfile
authorizedkeysfile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
```

For example, get the first one

```yaml
    - shell: sshd -T | grep authorizedkeysfile
      register: result
      become: true
    - set_fact:
        AuthorizedKeysFile: "{{ (result.stdout|split)[1] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  AuthorizedKeysFile: .ssh/authorized_keys
```

The parameter AuthorizedKeysFile may contain `%u` and `%h`. See [Location of the Authorized Keys File](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/authorized_keys/openssh#location-of-the-authorized-keys-file)

> %h will be replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, and %u by the login name of the user

Prepare the database of the home directories

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: passwd
```

By default, the module *getent* stores the database *passwd* in the dictionary *getent_passwd*. Home is the 4th attribute, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: getent_passwd['root'][4]
```

gives

```yaml
  getent_passwd['root'][4]: /root
```

Now, given the data

```yaml
    auth_keys:
      root: [key1, key2, key3]
```

you can test the functionality

```yaml
    - shell: sshd -T | grep authorizedkeysfile
      register: result
      become: true
    - set_fact:
        AuthorizedKeysFile: "{{ (result.stdout|split)[1] }}"
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - debug:
        msg: |
          path: {{ _path }}
          keys: {{ item.value }}
      loop: "{{ auth_keys|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        _user: "{{ item.key }}"
        _home: "{{ getent_passwd[item.key][4] }}"
        _akf: "{{ AuthorizedKeysFile|regex_replace('%u', _user)|
                                     regex_replace('%h', _home) }}"
        _path: "{{ (_akf.0 == '/')|ternary(_akf, [_home, _akf]|join('/')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    path: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    keys: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

If you change the parameter

```
shell> sudo sshd -T | grep authorizedkeysfile
authorizedkeysfile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
```

the play will get the correct location of the authorized keys file

```yaml
  msg: |-
    path: /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/root
    keys: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```